# Best way to keep checking for app updates

Tags: android, service

In my app I need to check for APK updates regularly ,
I have an API that retrieve the latest app version so by that i can check if the app runs an older version.

My question is what is the best way to keep checking for updates? shall I run a service say for every 30 min to check that?

Answer (score 0):

android already provide a solution for this you can use **in-app updates** from here
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Comment: Yeah but it's checking it at a one time only isn't?

Comment: @rav you specify how often you want your app to check for updates with the API, the library does nothing by itself

Comment: @tyczj Yes that's my question , shall i run a service that check for updates via my API? or is there better idea rather than service

Comment: @rav Other than killing the devices battery it really isnt going to be doing much to run as a service. Your service is only going to be running while your app is in the foreground, if you were thinking about making a foreground service to prevent that please dont create a foreground service that just keeps checking for your app update. Just check when the app launches, thats really all you need